# Motorola Moto G (2nd Gen) mobile hotspot not forwarding packets

Tags: motorola-moto-g, wifi-tethering

I have a Motorola Moto G (2nd Gen/2014) phone. I have set up a mobile hot spot, and when I activate it, my laptop can connect to it. I can ping the gateway, so the wifi connection between phone and laptop is working. On the phone I can browse and check mail, etc, so the phone's mobile data connection is working. But I cannot use the internet from the laptop. It's not a DNS issue, because I can't even ping my work server by its IP, nor some common DNS servers like google's or OpenDNS.

Has anyone else had this problem, and if so is there a solution or workaround?

EDIT: after doing further digging, it seems only IPv6 forwarding is being enabled, and of course without root you can't enable it.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the very same issue with MOTO E, MOto G2, 3 and Now with 4. everything works fine if i use Bluetooth tethering or USB tethering. as soon as i connect my Laptop with WiFi of the G4 (WiFi threatening option) it connects but shows a yellow mark over Wifi.

I tried every single trick available over Internet but nothing worked. finally i did a small change and everything became fine. what i did is as follows:

click on wifi symbol and go to the available networks--> find the network of your hotspot and right click--> go to connection properties --> change encryption type to "AES" if already selected go to advance setting--> click over check box (enable FIPS compliance)--> click ok --> click OK again and you are good to go.

i tried this on windows 8, things must be more or less same for windows 7 and 10.

Comment: Hi, I've since flashed my Moto G2 with cyanogenmod so I can no longer confirm this answer works. Hotspot works just fine now by the way. Thanks for the answer though.